# What is the probability of something having a chance of $90\%$ appear at least once in three tries? Also what is this concept called?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say I have this table of weights:

A: $90\%$

B: $2\%$

C: $3\%$

D: $5\%$

And I have three tries. If one succeeded, it will be taken out of the pool.

How can I calculate the chance that $A$ will occur at least once in $X$ tries?

Comment: What have you tried?  What mathematical tools or theory do you have at your disposal?  Where does this problem come from?

Comment: I tried this but doesnt seem to work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution Can you give me the concept so I can search more?

Comment: Hint:  it's easier to work from the complement.  The probability that $A$ does not occur on any given trial is $.1$ so the probability that it fails to occur in three independent trials is...

Comment: As to vocabulary:  the binomial distribution certainly does apply here...just think of the binary events $A$ and not$-A$.

Comment: But the probability here changes if one succeeded. For example if D succeeded then the chance for A is no longer 90% but 90/95

Answer (score 1):

As far as conceptualizing this, you can think blindly pulling socks from a drawer. 90 are blue, 2 are red, 3 are green, and 5 are black. Imagine you pull a black sock.  You would have had a 5/100 chance of doing this, and would remove all black socks after doing so. For your second pull you now have a 2/95 probability of pulling a red sock, 3/95 of a green, and 90/95 of a blue sock.

Consider all of the ways that you could pull three socks out and fail to pull out a blue one.

Black -> Green -> Red

Black -> Red-> Green

etc.

Every other case of pulls has to involve pulling out a blue sock...
Hopefully this helps for the early stages of working through this.